# Error in bash script switch case

Tags: bash

I want to create simple witch case in which I can execute functions based on user prompts:

```
echo Would you like us to perform the option: "(Y|N)"

read inPut

case $inPut in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code


# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
"N") echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
esac
```

But when I execute the script I get error:

```
Would you like us to perform the option: (Y|N)
n
run.sh: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
run.sh: line 27: `"N") echo 'Stopping execution''
EMP-SOF-LT099:Genesis Plamen$
```

Dow you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You need to break case statements with `;;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple issues.

1. Add a `;;` at end of each `case` construct
2. The `exit` command is misplaced within the `switch-case` construct without the `;;` present . It should be at the end of `case` or above.
3. `read` has a own option to print the message for user prompt, can avoid a unnecessary `echo`.

Error-free script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Would you like us to perform the option: \"(Y|N)\" " inPut

case $inPut in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code
;;


# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
"N") echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
;;

esac
```

Answer (score 2):

add ;;

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Would you like us to perform the option: "(Y|N)"

read inPut

case $inPut in
# echoing a command encapsulated by
# backticks (``) executes the command
"Y") echo 'Starting.....'
donwload_source_code


# depending on the scenario, execute the other option
# or leave as default
;;
"N") echo 'Stopping execution'
exit
;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code but the function is not called.

Comment: for the bash doesnot know the donwload_source_code. You may have to define it.